# ssh on remote server with nohup - not able to create files

Tags: ssh, centos7, nohup

I'm calling a shell script on a remote server with ssh `ssh user@host '/dir/myscript.sh'`and myscript.sh then runs another script with `nohup`, but the 2nd script isn't writing to nohup / to any other file with `echo "" > test.txt`.

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
source /home/user/.bash_profile

nohup /dir/myscript-real.sh > my.out 2> my.err < /dev/null &
```

**myscript-real.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
source /home/user/.bash_profile

echo -e "test"
sleep 15
echo "2nd test"
echo "test" > test.out
exit
```

When ran via SSH - no file is being created (my.out, my.err or test.out), but when running myscript.sh directly - those 3 files are being created.

Any ideas where is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What directory are you looking for those files in? Why do you think the files would be in that particular directory? What is the home directory for the user on the remote system?

Comment: @Kenster I've searched for the files at the same directory as the script(s). I also tried to use `./my.out` which didn't work as well, so I don't think that this is the problem. When I'm running myscript.sh directly - the files are being written as expected.

Comment: @Kenster you were right. The logs were saved at the user's home directory on the remote server. You should post it as an answer. Thanks!